# Evaluate the line integral $\int_{L} \frac{-y \,d x+x \,d y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ for a line segment $L$

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis, vector-fields, line-integrals

> Calculate the line integral
> $$
> \int_{L} \frac{-y \,d x+x \,d y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}
> $$
> where $L$ is the line segment from $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$ parametrized by
> $$
> L(t)=(1-t)(1,0)+t(0,1), \quad 0 \leq t \leq 1
> $$

I know I can calculate by normal parametrization, but the answer says it represents the argument changed; could someone please explain this?

> The integral measures the change in argument along the curve $L$.
> $$
> \int_{L} \frac{-y \,d x+x \,d y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=\frac{\pi}{2}
> $$

And another question I have is that when I compute this integral using change of potential, I found the potential of this vector field to be $$-\arctan\frac{x}{y}+c ,$$ but that function is not defined at the endpoint $(1, 0)$ of $L$.

Comment: Have you tried  writing the integral in polar coordinates?

Comment: nope, because L(t) is not a circle right? its the line y=1-x,

Comment: If you write it in polar coordinates you might notice that the integral does not depend on the path, but only on the initial and final points.

Comment: could you please explain more, maybe writing it down would be helpful, I would really appreciate that

Comment: @Andrei is alluding to the fact that for a closed differential $df$ in a region, the value of the line integral depends only on the endpoints of the curve contained in the region. So, if you showed the differential is closed, you could use the segment of a circle as your curve instead. If you don't want to use that, still try polar coordinates; the line segment can be parametrized as $r=\cos(\theta)$, $ 0\leq \theta \leq \pi/2$

Comment: oh okey it makes a bit sence now, thank you! Is it because the line integral is route irrelevant(no matter which route we take as long as we keep the  endpoints  the integral stays the  same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the quarter arc: $\gamma:[0,\pi/2]\to \mathbf{R}^2$ with
$$
\gamma(t) = (\cos(t),\sin(t))
$$
with the direction from $\gamma(0)$ to $\gamma(1)$. Then $\int_L Pdx+Qdy=\int_\gamma Pdx+Qdy$ by [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem), where
$$
P(x,y)=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\quad Q(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\;,
$$
because the closed path $L-\gamma$ is contained in an open simply connected subset of $\mathbf{R}^2$ where the vector field is smooth and $P_y=Q_x$.
By working on the line integral along $\gamma$, you can easily find the expected answer $\pi/2$ mentioned in your post:
$$
\int_\gamma Pdx+Qdy=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\bigg((-\sin(t))(-\sin(t))+\cos(t)\cos(t)\bigg)\;dt = \frac{\pi}{2}\;.
$$

The vector field $(P,Q)$ does not have a potential function on the punctured plane $\mathbf{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. So when you work on a potential function, you need to specify the (simply connected) domain of your vector field.

Answer (score 2):

The "change in argument" is, informally, just the total net angle that the path winds around the origin anticlockwise (a negative change in argument indicates a net clockwise winding). We can see this from a computation similar to the one that gave you a potential of a restriction of $$\omega := \frac{-y \,dx + x \,dy}{x^2 + y^2} .$$ This description of $\omega$ motivates the common notation $d\theta$ for that form, but we'll see below that $\omega$ is not exact, i.e., isn't the exterior derivative of any function, so that notation can be misleading.

Indeed, integrating $\omega$ gives the function
$$f(x, y) := \arctan \frac{y}{x} ;$$
strictly speaking $f$ is not a potential for $\omega$ but rather a potential for the restriction of $\omega$ to the domain $H := \{x \neq 0\}$ of $f$. (This phenomenon explains why you ran into trouble evaluating your potential at a point on one of the axes.) Drawing a triangle with vertices $(0, 0), (x, 0), (x, y)$ (with, say, $x > 0$) and using the usual definition of the arctangent function shows that $f(x, y)$ is just the signed angle between the positive $x$-axis and the ray from the origin through $(x, y)$. Thus, for a differentiable parametrized curve $\gamma : [a, b] \to H$ in the right half-plane, the F.T.C. gives that
$\int_\gamma \omega$ is just the total (net) angle the curve winds, starting with $\gamma(a)$ and ending at $\gamma(b)$.

To extend this notion to any path $\gamma: [a, b] \to \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$ notice $\omega$ is rotationally symmetric, so our conclusion must hold for any path whose image is contained inside an open half-plane passing through the origin. At this point we can conclude that $\int_L \omega$ is the signed angle between $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ with respect to the origin, namely $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

But we can partition the curve $\gamma$ into pieces such that each piece is contained inside such a half-plane, hence the value of $\int_\gamma \omega$ is the sum of the net angles $\gamma$ winds over each subinterval, that is, just the total net angle $\gamma$ winds around the origin, as claimed.

---

Notice that integrating $\omega$ along the unit circle $S^1$ (oriented anticlockwise) thus gives
$$\int_{S^1} \omega = 2 \pi .$$ In particular, the integral of $\omega$ along some closed path is nonzero, hence the F.T.C. implies that $\omega$ is not exact, i.e., has no potential.

That said, we can still use a potential to compute the line integral over the line segment $L$. One method is to (again) use rotational symmetry: For any rotation $f \circ R$ must again be a potential for the restriction of $\omega$ to its domain, so it's enough to pick an angle of rotation such that $L$ is contained in a single half-plane, and, e.g., $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ will do. Simplifying gives the potential
$$(f \circ R)(x, y) = \arctan \frac{y - x}{x + y}$$ of the restriction of $\omega$ to the half-plane $\{x + y > 0\}$ containing $L$, so that
$$\int_L \omega = \int_L d(f \circ R) = \int_{\partial L} (f \circ R) = (f \circ R)\bigg\vert_{(1, 0)}^{(0, 1)} = \frac{\pi}{2} .$$

Comment: thank you very much for answering but this seems a bit advanced for me to understand  fully :D

Answer (score 1):

Let's write your integral as $$\int_L\vec f d\vec r$$
In Cartesian coordinates $$d\vec r=\hat x dx+\hat y dy$$  so then $$\vec f=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\hat x+\frac x{x^2+y^2}\hat y$$
In polar coordinates $$d\vec r=dr\hat r+rd\theta\hat \theta$$
Here $$\hat r=\frac xr\hat x+\frac yr\hat y$$ and $$\hat\theta=-\frac yr\hat x+\frac xr\hat y$$
Then it's easy to see that in polar coordinates $$\vec f=\frac1r\hat\theta$$
Therefore $$\vec f d\vec r=d\theta$$
Therefore $$\int_L\vec f d\vec r=\int_Ld\theta=\theta_{end}-\theta_{start}$$

Comment: This is a very nice solution.